# While loop doesn't stop when it has to

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, while-loop

So I'm trying to create a program which has to ask what the weather is for a certain day for 7 days and it cannot be "overvloed" which means 'flooding'. although both when i've reached my 7 days or when i type "overvloed" the loop doesn't seem to stop, how can i fix this? (sorry for the code, its in dutch)

```
def main():
teller = 1
dagen = []

temp = int(input("Voer de temperatuur in: "))
neerslag = input("Hoeveelheid neerslag(overvloed - veel – matig – geen): ")
while teller < 8 or neerslag != "overvloed":
    temp = int(input("Voer de temperatuur in: "))
    neerslag = input("Hoeveelheid neerslag(overvloed - veel – matig – geen): ")
    dagen.append(teller)
    teller += 1

if neerslag == "overvloed":
    print("Uitstap gaat NIET door")

print(dagen[teller])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You need `and` instead of `or` in the while condition.

Comment: Maybe you mean to use an `and` for your loop, I.E run the loop while teller is less than 8 and neerslag is not overvloed. that way when one of them is not true the loop will stop

Comment: As written this will ask *at least* 7 times and then only stop when you enter "overvloed"…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to use `and` instead of `or`